# Macbook Pro 2012 works with secondary monitor, but integrated screen remains black

Tags: macos, display, macbook-pro

Yesterday I was using Microsoft Excel 2011 to do my accounts and the screen suddenly went black.  I tried restarting but this did not solve the problem.

I have connected to another monitor (also Mac) by mini thunderbolt and am now able to view my files/ run backup/ etc., so all the files are safe.

My question is: **What has caused this failure??**  If I knew the cause I am sure I could fix it myself.

I have tried the suggestions on several apple forums including:

1. Resetting the System Management Controller.
2. Resetting PRAM.
3. Checking brightness controls.

For example: http://osxdaily.com/2014/11/22/fix-macbook-pro-booting-black-screen/

This is a MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012) running Yosemite 10.10.5.  It is out of warranty and I have had no response from apple support.

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer:* Although I have a Mac I am not an expert!

If I was in your position, I would take a look at the [console logs](https://support.omnigroup.com/console-osx/) and do further research on root cause from here.

Comment: Ok, I have done that, but what should I be looking for?